# Remove duplicates returning from join

Tags: sql, duplicates, records

I'm attempting to join two tables.  Each table has a unique ID.  Upon joining, multiple records are returned (many to one relationship).  How can I avoid the duplication of records and obtain one matching record.

Join criteria used is on email and date field:

```
select 1.email, 1.lead_id, 1.lead_date, 2.rdm_id
from table_1 
   inner join table_2 on 1.email=2.email and 1.lead_date = 2.post_date
```

**Table 1:**

```
email, lead_id, lead_date
124@gmail.com, 1655535, 1/1/2013
124@gmail.com, 1655536, 1/1/2013
```

**Table 2:**

```
email, rdm_id, post_date
124@gmail.com, 3283370, 1/1/2013
124@gmail.com, 3283373, 1/1/2013
```

I'd like my output to be:

```
124@gmail.com, 1655535, 3283370, 1/1/2013
124@gmail.com, 1655536, 3283373, 1/1/2013
```

Currently returning:

```
124@gmail.com, 1655535, 3283370, 1/1/2013
124@gmail.com, 1655536, 3283370, 1/1/2013
124@gmail.com, 1655535, 3283373, 1/1/2013
124@gmail.com, 1655536, 3283373, 1/1/2013
```

Comment: What have you already tried? What gave you multiple rows per "record?" It's easier for us to improve existing code than write it new.

Comment: Your rows are not duplicates.  Please explain the logic for choosing the rows that you want and tag the question with the database you are using.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: Using MySQL when performing the inner join email and date, it doesn't know how to distinguish which record (lead_id) goes with the corresponding rdm_id.  Using a distinct or group by does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Just use distinct or group by to remove duplicates.

```
select distinct ....
```

or

```
your_sql_query
group by email, num1, num2, date
```

Comment: Distinct will not remove any of the rows in the ("currently returning") example. There are not duplicates in that result.

Comment: The query is being run in MySQL DB.  I've tried Distinct and Group By, but neither works.

Comment: Of course neither work, they are not duplicate rows.

Comment: @Erick That is my bad, I didn't see the differences between row two.  How do you choose which column valeus to choose from two and three?

Comment: In most cases there is a 1:1 relationship so the join works, but in cases where there are multiple submissions with the same email address on the same day, that's where I'm stuck.  The only other unique characteristic is the timestamp in the dates.  I didn't include that in my post, but here's an example   
TABLE 1:
id / date_created
1655535 / 1/1/2013 4:39:16 AM
1655536 / 1/1/2013 4:43:18 AM

TABLE 2:

3283370 1/1/2013 5:42:08 AM
3283373 1/1/2013 5:46:08 AM

Comment: Resulting Join I'd like:
id // date_created // RIDM // post_date
1655535  //  1/1/2013 4:39:16 AM // 3283370 //  1/1/2013 5:42:08 AM
1655536  //  1/1/2013 4:43:18 AM  // 3283373 1/1/2013 5:46:08 AM

Comment: @Erick Can you just select the row with the min timestamp out of the duplicate emails?